# Page binding overrides url hooks

Tags: symfony, routes, bolt-cms

In a custom extension I have created a few URL hooks as follows:

```
namespace MyExtension;

class Extension extends \Bolt\BaseExtension
{   

    public function initialize()
    {
        // audio sample management
        $this->app->match("/foo", array($this, 'foo'));
        $this->app->match("/bar", array($this, 'bar'));
    }

    function foo()
    {
        // ...
    }

    function bar()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I can hit both these functions via a url like so:

- example.com/foo
- example.com/bar

... and both will execute.

However when I add a page binding into the `routing.yml` it breaks and it tries to look for `foo` and `bar` as if they were `pages`.

```
pagebinding:
  path: /{slug}
  defaults: { _controller: 'Bolt\Controllers\Frontend::record', 'contenttypeslug': 'page' }
  contenttype: pages
```

How can I have `foo` and `bar` without them being caught by this binding?

**SOLUTION**

Added the following routing snippet before my `pagebinding` route.

```
foobinding:
  path: /foo
  defaults: { _controller: 'MyExtension\Extension::foo' }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a sticky one and "by design" in Silex/Symfony. The controller routes getting stacked, and first match wins.

In Bolt, `initMountpoints()` (where the `routes.yml` routes get set up) gets called just before `initExtensions()` so the application routes can't get wiped out by poorly designed or malicious extensions.

What I have done on one install is to set the extension routes in `routing.yml` and define the controller as `MyExtension\Extension`.

**UPDATE**
Here is what is in the routing.yml file that I am using, but on Bolt 2 beta.

`sitemap:
  path:               /sitemap.xml
  defaults:           { _controller: 'Bolt\Extension\Gawain\CustomSitemap\Controller\Sitemap::sitemap' }`

Note that the extended namespace is just compliance with version 2 standards, not special in regards to 'working'

Comment: Do you have to do something special in the Extension for that? I've tried it but I get Unable to find controller "MyExtension\Extension". Adding binding setup above in case I did that wrong.

Comment: Got it. Cheers for the help.